# TypeScript typeguard attribut with method

Tags: typescript

Simple stuff, I have:

```js
public async get(): Promise<Data> {
    if (this.cache !== null) return this.cache;

    // Do things to fill cache
}
```

I now needed a second check to validate the cache. So I thought it would be neat if I extracted `this.cache !== null` into a method called `isCachePresent`. The resulting code would look something like this

```js
public async getMap(): Promise<Data> {
    if (this.isCachePresent() && this.isCacheValid()) return this.cache;

    // Do things to fill cache
}
```

But now typescritp obviously complains that `this.cache` may be `null`. How do I add a typeguard for that method?.

I've seen this online

```js
private cacheIsPresent(): this is this & {cache: Data} {
    return this.cache !== null;
}
```

Now typescript is unhappy with: `Property 'cache' does not exist on type 'never'. The intersection 'this & { cache: Data }' was reduced to 'never' because property 'cache' exists in multiple constituents and is private in some.`

**Edit:** Mind that the `cache` is actually private, and should remain private. [Minimal reproducible example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOUC8UDOwBOBLAdgcwG4AoYgYwBs400oAxAewagG9ioowcA3BaMuGQAWEAFywESAD5RcAVwoUUshRRLtOcgEYVsZKNRC59+CMAAUASnEAFTAwC22NBAA88RAD5WGjtgBmUObAQs4AdM4AwoIidhAuuBaWllCYZnKYuFAh4QLCECQcHDloYXkiygBEIorMAO4MmBQAJpWFRWnAGVklZTEFGgC+pBxc2LzA0FH9cQlJ4iVQzqzlYhKIgz5FqemZ2aGlq1AAhMio8ortw4NAA)

Comment: Your typeguard seems to be working for me: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOUC8UDOwBOBLAdgcwG4AoYgYwBs400oBZEAYSpqgG9iouowBXAIwrYyUMnDIALCAC5YCJAB8ouXhQoooAcgoB7TBAC2UbGDS8Dmkp259BwqNRC4R+CMDpwwACgCUsgAqYOgbYaBAAPPCIAHzs1tzc2ABmUF7AEqEAdKGM4lKBEGG4wL4+UPrAvJi4UOlZYpIQVgkJAPStsDq1GQS0wF1J2GqieRDxLRVVNZpJOjr8cJiW4wC+pAlgOABuCNA5owVFJX7docZ9GbQAZOwNUrJRcCtxLdyT1adomXfQAITIqBUahICTWayAA

Comment: @Terry Yes :D, mind that my cache is actually private though, and should not be exposed to the public.

Comment: @Thomas Yes, for some reason I thought that would be obvious. Added it :)

Comment: Try `this is Data` ?

Comment: @Dai `Type 'Data | null' is not assignable to type 'Data'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Data'.`. I would have been really surprised if this worked. I'm not returning `this` I'm returning `this.cache`.

Comment: @Elias I think you're getting distracted by the public/private state of `cache`. What really matters is if the typeguard works or not, and it seems to do: so what's your question?

Comment: @Terry My question is: "How to I get the typeguard to work, without typescript giving me the error I posted at the very bottom of the question".

Comment: [Minimal reproducible example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOUC8UDOwBOBLAdgcwG4AoYgYwBs400oAxAewagG9ioowcA3BaMuGQAWEAFywESAD5RcAVwoUUshRRLtOcgEYVsZKNRC59+CMAAUASnEAFTAwC22NBAA88RAD5WGjtgBmUObAQs4AdM4AwoIidhAuuBaWllCYZnKYuFAh4QLCECQcHDloYXkiygBEIorMAO4MmBQAJpWFRWnAGVklZTEFGgC+pBxc2LzA0FH9cQlJ4iVQzqzlYhKIgz5FqemZ2aGlq1AAhMio8ortw4NAA). You might want to include this in your post because there seems to be some confusion.

Answer (score 2):

The [rules for type compatibility](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#understanding-typescripts-private) require that two `private` fields originate in the same declaration. Since one of them is from `private cache` in your class, and the other one is from `{cache: Data}` where `cache` isn't private at all, these types aren't compatible and the intersection `this & {cache: Data}` is empty (`never`).

What works is to make `cache` a `protected` field instead of `private`. This still protects it from access outside the class, so it serves much the same purpose. If you don't have any subclasses, there is no widened access, so no problem.

However, I don't understand *why* this works. According to the rules, "the same applies to `protected` members" as to `private` ones.

Personally I would just use `return this.cache!;` in this case.

Comment: Yeah, my current solution is `if (this.cacheIsPresent() && this.cacheIsValid())
   return this.cache as Data;`. But that kinda defeats the purpose of typeguards.

Comment: In that case `!` is safer because it only allows conversions from a nullable `Data` to a non-nullable `Data`, not from any arbitrary type to a `Data`.

Comment: Now eslint is complaining about "Forbidden non-null assertion.". Sure, I may ignore that.

Answer (score 1):

Adding another answer with a somewhat nicer solution: the `isCachePresent` function is trivial, and writing `this.isCachePresent()` is actually longer than writing `this.cache` (or `this.cache !== null` if you must). So you can just inline it, which allows the type guard to work:

```
if (this.cache && this.isCacheValid()) return this.cache;
```

Comment: I already wanted to post a comment about this earlier, but sadly you deleted it. You are right that in **this particular case** this would create nice code. But in other cases, for example with strings, I consider such "truthy/falsy" operations dangerous. That's why I got into the habit of **always** explicitly checking `null`/`undefined`

Comment: Indeed it depends on the type of `this.cache` whether or not the shorthand is a good idea. And even if it's safe it also depends on personal taste.

Comment: Yes, and in my case it would be fine. I guess I should start using those assertions when absolutely sure the values are not strings or numbers (or any other of the javascript quirks).